# Can Redshift SQL perform a case insensitive regular expression evaluation?

Tags: regex, posix, amazon-redshift, pcre

The documentation says regexp_instr() and ~ are case sensitive Posix evaluating function and operator.
Is there a Posix syntax for case insensitive, or a plug-in for PCRE based function or operator

Example of PCRE tried in a Redshift query that don't work as desired because of POSIX'ness.

```
select 
  A.target
, B.pattern
, regexp_instr(A.target, B.pattern) as rx_instr_position
, A.target ~ B.pattern as tilde_operator
, regexp_instr(A.target
, 'm/'||B.pattern||'/i') as rx_instr_position_icase
from
(      select 'AbCdEfffghi' as target 
 union select 'Chocolate' as target 
 union select 'Cocoa Latte' as target 
 union select 'coca puffs, delivered late' as target
) A
,
(      select 'choc.*late' as pattern 
 union select 'coca.*late' as pattern 
 union select 'choc\w+late' as pattern
 union select 'choc\\w+late' as pattern
) B
```

Comment: What pattern do you want to use with a POSIX regex flavor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question: No Redshift-compatible syntax or plugins that I know of. In case you could live with a workaround: We ended up using `lower()` around the strings to match:

```
select
  A.target
, B.pattern
, regexp_instr(A.target, B.pattern) as rx_instr_position
, A.target ~ B.pattern as tilde_operator
, regexp_instr(A.target, 'm/'||B.pattern||'/i') as rx_instr_position_icase
, regexp_instr(lower(A.target), B.pattern) as rx_instr_position_icase_by_lower
from
(      select 'AbCdEfffghi' as target
 union select 'Chocolate' as target
 union select 'Cocoa Latte' as target
 union select 'coca puffs, delivered late' as target
) A
,
(      select 'choc.*late' as pattern 
 union select 'coca.*late' as pattern 
 union select 'choc\w+late' as pattern
 union select 'choc\\w+late' as pattern
) B
```

Answer (score 3):

`select 'HELLO' ~* 'el'` = true

this is currently undocumented (2020-11-05)

Answer (score 1):

Redshift now provides a direct solution for case-insensitive regular expression flags via added function parameters: [Amazon Redshift - REGEXP_INSTR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_INSTR.html)

The syntax using the provided query example would be:

```
select
  A.target
, B.pattern
, regexp_instr(A.target, B.pattern) as rx_instr_position
, A.target ~ B.pattern as tilde_operator
, regexp_instr(A.target, B.pattern, 1, 1, 0, 'i') AS rx_instr_position_icase
from
(      select 'AbCdEfffghi' as target
 union select 'Chocolate' as target
 union select 'Cocoa Latte' as target
 union select 'coca puffs, delivered late' as target
) A
,
(      select 'choc.*late' as pattern 
 union select 'coca.*late' as pattern 
 union select 'choc\w+late' as pattern
 union select 'choc\\w+late' as pattern
) B
```